# All the elements of subarray whose sum is maximum where elements are taken from given array such that no two elements are adjacent?

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic

I have written a code that will give me all the elements of sub array whose sum is maximum where elements are taken from given array such that no two elements are adjacent. But it is failing for some of the test cases which I don't know , what is the mistake I am doing

```
global a



a = list(map(int , input().split()))
global DP
global neg_
global sum_seq
sum_seq = [0]*len(a)


def solve(i):
    k = 1
    a1 = []
    b1 = []
    while i + 1:
        if i == len(a) - 1 or i == len(a) - 2:
            if i == len(a) - 1:
                a1.append(a[i])
                sum_seq[i] = a[i]
            if i == len(a) - 2:
                if a[i] > sum_seq[i + 1]:
                    b1.append(a[i])
                    sum_seq[i] = a[i]
                else:
                    b1.append(a[i+1])
                    sum_seq[i] = sum_seq[i+1]
        else:
            if k % 2:
                if sum_seq[i + 1] < sum_seq[i+2] + a[i]:
                    a1.append(a[i])
                    sum_seq[i] = sum_seq[i+2] + a[i]
                    k += 1
                else:
                    sum_seq[i] = sum_seq[i+1]
                    a1.clear()
                    a1 = b1[:]
                    k += 1  
            else:
                if sum_seq[i+1] < sum_seq[i+2] + a[i]:
                    b1.append(a[i])
                    sum_seq[i] = sum_seq[i+2] + a[i]
                    k += 1
                else:
                    sum_seq[i] = sum_seq[i+1]
                    b1.clear()
                    b1 = a1[:]
                    k += 1
        i -= 1
    print(*a1)
    print(*b1)
    print(sum(a1))
    print(sum(b1))
solve(len(a) - 1)
```

Here , final output will be the max of sum of a1 or b1.